# SSRS Grouping Aggregate

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I'm having an issue creating some grouping in SSRS.  I can't use SQL.

Basically I have a set of data I want to turn into a pivot or summary table.  I can SUM revenue by ownerID no problem, but they have some teaming and filters on their report I can't replicate.  This is the basic table:

```
Employee    Quote Revenue
User1       SUM by ownerID
User2       SUM by ownerID
User3       SUM by ownerID
User4       SUM by ownerID
User5       SUM by ownerID
User 6      SUM by ownerID
```

This is what they would like to measure

```
Teaming/Filter      Quote Revenue
User 1 & User 2     SUM by Group
User 3 & User 4     SUM by Group
User 5 where customer type=1        SUM by Filter
User 5 where customer type=2        SUM by Filter
User 6      SUM by Owner ID
```

I've used SUM by a group name and I've tried SUM IIF but they either don't work or I get the revenue on separate rows.  Would appreciate any advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My approach here would be to use a one row Tablix for each measure. That way, you can set the filter, and grouping for each scenario in its own Tablix, instead of attempting to do this in one. This keeps with the no SQL restriction. As far as display on the report, you can align each Tablix, and hide the headers, so it looks like one table in the end.

It’s not the most elegant solution in the world, but it should work.

More detail for one of the measures (User 1 and User 2 revenue):

1. Add a Tablix to the report
2. In the Tablix properties, set the dataset name to proper dataset
3. In the Filters properties for the Tablix, set the filter to what is need for the specific measure. You will have to use the In operator for the measures where you are teaming more than one user. In this case it will be something like “User1”, “User2” for the Value of a filter where the Expression is UserID, and the Operator is In. SSRS will change what the Value looks like in the designer, so you may have to play around with it duplicating quotes
4. In the Row Groups pane, for the (Details) row group, change the Group Properties group expression to use a field in the dataset that each row in the filter shares. Maybe a date, or a quote number in this case. You are not going to display this value so what it is is not important, just as long as it is the same for each row in the data you are filtering on.
5. In the first column of the Tablix, set the detail value to a string describing what you are showing, “User 1 and User 2”, in this instance.
6. In the second column of the Tablix, make the expression the sum of the revenue.

   `=Sum(Fields!revenue.Value)`
7. Hide the header row
8. Run the report

I know this is a lot, but once you do one, you can copy and paste the Tablix, and adjust to new copy for the next measure. Hopefully, you don’t have a ton of measures! If you do, then a really need to think about doing this with SQL.